# How to redirect if slug contains certain word?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'd like to redirect if my slug contains /product-category/. So for example...

[www.mysite.com/product-category/](http://www.mysite.com/product-category/) ---> redirect to [www.mysite.com/shop](http://www.mysite.com/shop)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in functions.php

```
function curPageURL() {

$pageURL = 'http';

if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}

$pageURL .= "://";

if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {

    $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];

} else {

    $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];

}

return $pageURL;  }
```

Then add the following in header.php

```
$url = curPageURL();
$url_array = explode("/", $url);
if(in_array("product-category",$url_array))
{ header("Location:www.mysite.com/shop"); }
```